# Query of json arrays containing objects

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, where-clause, mysql-json

It is stored in MySQL DB in the form below.

"config" is a JSON type and it's an array of objects.

I want to query the data that has "config" containing the object "type" is "download".

(i.e. data with "id=test2" and "id=test3" in the example below)

I'm having a lot of trouble doing queries that include JSON type.

```
"id":"test1", "config":[{"type": "get", "request": {}}]
"id":"test2", "config":[{"type": "set", "request": {}}, {"type": "download", "request": {}}]
"id":"test3", "config":[{"type": "download", "request": {}}, {"type": "reset", "request": {}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `json_extract()` and `json_contains()`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where json_contains(json_extract(config, '$[*].type'), '"download"')
```